# How to insert an element into a particular node in a NOT well formed XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Newbie needing help here.

I am dealing with a file that's only "mostly" XML so that might be part of my problem.  Also, I am learning C# as I go along (I'm a Visual Basic programmer from way back.) so that's slowing me down a lot!

The structure of the file looks something like this:

```
<Book>
  <bookObjects>
    <HardCover>
      <pagesList>
      <pages id = "123" />
      <pages id = "456" />
      <pages id = "789" />
      </pagesList>
    </HardCover>

    <!-- some valid XML followed by a bunch of elements that look like this -->
    <dm>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt; 
     &lt;java version="1.6.0_19" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"&gt; 
     &lt;object class="java.util.LinkedList"&gt; 
     &lt;void method="add"&gt; 
     &lt;object class="java.util.HashMap"&gt; 
     <!-- etc, this is just a sample -->
    </dm>

    <pagesList>
     <pages id = "987" />
     <pages id = "654" />
     <pages id = "321" /> <!-- I want to insert before this line -->
    </pagesList>
 </bookObjects>
</Book>
```

So my problem is that I want to add some more pages to the SECOND pagesList node/element/whatchacallit, the one that is not within the HardCover node.  (Forgive me if I've got the words wrong, like I said, brand new to all this.)

I have tried OH so many things.  I either get null results or else I get the first one, the one inside HardCover.

Here's what I've got currently, which writes to the wrong one.

```
    private void WriteToFile ()
    {
        // Get the output file as an xml document
        //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(outputBook.ToString());
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(outputBook.ToString());



        //Find the pagesList node

        //This doesn't work: it only gets the first one despite not being at the root
        //XmlNode foundNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//pagesList");
        XmlNode foundNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Book//bookObjects//pagesList");
        if (foundNode != null)
        {

            XmlElement eleItem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("InsertTest");
            eleItem.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
            foundNode.AppendChild(eleItem);

        }
        //doc.Save(outputBook.ToString());
        xmlDoc.Save(outputBook.ToString());
    }
```

Resulting file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Book id="stuff deleted from example" >
  <bookObjects>
     <HardCover id="bf9a0769-23b0-4da7-bf81-b63034ec7704">
       <pagesList>
         <pages id="991da2a8-d2ac-45fb-b325-92cae2a5613f" />
         <pages id="f66107c7-a4a8-487f-857a-6e53637ff085" />
         <InsertTest>12:49:20 AM</InsertTest> <!-- darn you!  wrong spot! -->
      </pagesList>
    </HardCover>
```

I've tried XmlDocument and XDocument.  I've tried putting in single slashes, double slashes, dots at the beginning.  So many things.  But not the right thing.

I'd be happy (at the moment) just being able to get the correct pagesList node... I do need to insert my new elements one prior to whatever is the current last element eventually, as indicated by the comment above.  (i.e. The last one must remain the last one.)

**UPDATE:**
I'm an idiot.  So, so sorry!  /Book/bookObjects/pagesList was not the right path at all.  I wanted /Book/pagesList.  No wonder it returned null.  (That's what I get for staying up two hours past my bedtime banging my head against this wall.)

So now I've got it targeting the right section; I just need to get it into the correct position next.

Comment: This XML is not well-formed, the `<pages>` elements are not closed. But from your question, I'm guessing this is not your real problem?

Comment: "I am dealing with a file that's only "mostly" XML so that might be part of my problem." I suspect that's the first thing you should address, even if it turns out there are further issues. I wouldn't try to use XML APIs for invalid XML - they're generally not designed to do that. Can you fix the XML first? (I'd also recommend using XDocument rather than XmlDocument - it's just a simpler API to use. For example, XDocument makes it really easy to select an element without using XPath at all.)

Comment: Looks like you file is mostly html with the dm tags being xml.

Comment: Sorry, I typed in and simplified the initial file to illustrate the problem and left it kind of screwed up (not closing the pages tags) but the one at the bottom is a real copy/paste of the file.

Comment: And I can't fix the file; I'm basically trying to add a feature to a COTS application by modifying their data files.  Blurb BookSmart doesn't have an "import page from another book" feature and it should :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath, `//`  means 'anywhere below here', not just direct children.

I think you'll have more luck with this XPath query: `"/Book/bookObjects/pagesList"`.

Comment: When I change the line to this:
`XmlNode foundNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Book/bookObjects/pagesList");`

Then I get `foundNode == null`.

Comment: But when I stop being dumb and put `/Book/pagesList` which is where the node I want is REALLY located, it works great.